# Fluent forms action hook, i can't modify the entries before submit

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

What am i doing wrong? i can't modify the entries before it submit in my db. Any help? thanks in advance

```
add_action('fluentform_before_insert_submission', 'insert_data', 10, 3);

function insert_data($insertData, $data, $form){
    
   if($form->id != 3) {
      return;
   }
    
    $invitation = $data['id'];
    
    if(empty($invitation)){
        
        $data = $insertData['response'];
        $answer = json_decode($datos);
        $list = array(
        "__fluent_form_embded_post_id"      => '18',
        "_fluentform_3_fluentformnonce"     => 'f2a87fd348',
        "_wp_http_referer"          => '/reg/',
        "id"                        => '',
        "group"                 => '2',
        "number"                => '2',
        "id_medic"              => '3TDca98S',
        "email_medic"               => 'medic3@mail.com',
        "account_medic"             => 'basic'
        );
        $mod = json_encode($arreglo);
        $insertData['response'] = $mod;
    }
    return $insertData
}
```

i try to many ways and i can't get this done.

Im triying to modify the group and number, these entries are empty by default and want to change them with the value 2 on each case before the insert to the data base.

please help.

Comment: https://fluentforms.com/docs/fluentform_before_insert_submission/ makes it sound like the purpose of this hook was extra validation, but not to actually manipulate the input data. Have you tried making your callback function take `$insertData` as reference, instead of returning it?

Answer (score 0):

the hook has actually been renamed:
https://developers.fluentforms.com/hooks/actions/#submission-specific

add_action('fluentform/before_insert_submission', 'functionName', 10, 3);